# SQL to retrieve one of several rows grouped by 1 field while retaining multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have not been able to wrap my head around how to create a GROUP BY query with SQL in Access 2013 to accomplish retrieving just 1 row per "group" based on the MAX value in one of the columns for multi-column data while retaining **all** the columns.

I want to return only 1 [ClientID] row with the MAX of [SupervisorID].  I don't care which [DispositionID] is returned.

Here is (part) of what I have for data (there are many more columns than this that I must retain):

```
ClientID    LastName    FirstName   Sex     DispositionID   SupervisorID
6263        Junk        Danny       M       1222            322
6263        Junk        Danny       M       1223            Null
6263        Junk        Danny       M       1220            322
6260        Fake        Angie       F       1208            206
6244        Junker      Adam        M       1153            322
6244        Junker      Adam        M       1148            Null
6257        Junkly      Summer      F       1218            Null
6257        Junkly      Summer      F       1179            Null
```

[ClientID], [LastName], [FirstName], and [Sex] are pulled from Table A.

[DispositionID] is pulled from Table B (linked on [ClientID]).

[SupervisorID] is pulled from Table C (linked on [DispositionID]).

The target query would return this:

```
ClientID    LastName    FirstName   Sex     DispositionID   SupervisorID
6263        Junk        Danny       M       1220            322
6260        Fake        Angie       F       1208            206
6244        Junker      Adam        M       1153            322
6257        Junkly      Summer      F       1179            Null
```

Once I have the target query, I'll have to do a UNION of that query with another (similar) query, although I imagine that will not influence how to accomplish this first query.

Once the two queries are UNIONed, I'll have to filter that query to show just rows with either a specific [SupervisorID] (e.g., 322) OR a Null [SupervisorID].

I also tried the SELECT DISTINCT but that still returned multiple [ClientID]s instead of just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select x.clientid,
       x.lastname,
       x.firstname,
       x.sex,
       min(y.dispositionid) as dispositionid,
       x.supervisorid
  from (select clientid,
               lastname,
               firstname,
               sex,
               max(supervisorid) as supervisorid
          from tbl
         group by clientid, lastname, firstname, sex) x
 inner join tbl y
    on x.clientid = y.clientid
   and x.supervisorid = y.supervisorid
 group by x.clientid, x.lastname, x.firstname, x.sex, x.supervisorid
union all
select x.clientid,
       x.lastname,
       x.firstname,
       x.sex,
       min(x.dispositionid),
       x.supervisorid
  from tbl x
 where not exists (select 1
          from tbl y
         where y.supervisorid is not null
           and y.clientid = x.clientid)
 group by x.clientid, x.lastname, x.firstname, x.sex, x.supervisorid
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d315/12/0
(matches your desired output)

Comment: Thanks @Brian. It's **really** close. The output does match my desired output for the data posted. However, I should have specified that a ClientID can have multiple DispositionIDs and the same SupervisorID can be assigned to each DispositionID.

So, if a SupervisorID appears more than once for the same ClientID (e.g., the ClientID has 2 DispositionIDs with the same SupervisorID for each DispositionID) then I get multiple rows for that ClientID.

I.e., it lists ClientID 6263 twice with new data. I need ClientID just once. I don't care what DispositionID is shown/lost. I'll edit original data.

Comment: @user3862163 I just updated the sql so that the first part of the query will show only the first disposition for the max(supervisor). That way if the max(supervisor) has 2+ disposition IDs, only the first will be listed. Does that work now?

Comment: YES!  That works beautifully.  I've got to study that SQL to sort out how it's all working together.  Many thanks.

Comment: For others who may find this post in the future: I tweaked the code to Access's SQL demands. Specifically, I used "MIN(y.dispositionid) AS MINdispositionid" vs "min(y.dispositionid) as dispositionid".  Used "x.MAXsupervisorid" vs "x.supervisorid". Used "max(supervisorid) as MAXsupervisorid" vs "max(supervisorid) as supervisorid". Used "and x.MAXsupervisorid = y.supervisorid" vs "and x.supervisorid = y.supervisorid". Used "x.MAXsupervisorid" vs "x.supervisorid" in the *first* group by (but not the last group by).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky because of the `NULL` values.  This should work:

```
select d.*
from data as d inner join
     (select clientId, max(dispositionid) as maxd, max(superviserid) as maxs
      from data
      group by clientid
     ) as c
     on d.clientId = c.clientId and
        (d.supervisorId = c.maxs or
         c.maxs is null and d.dispositionid = c.maxd
        );
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon.  Unfortunately, when I tried out that SQL it returns the same values as the original table.  My only change to the code listed was to change "data" to the name of my table that has the data in it (i.e., Table1 in my test database).

Comment: @user3862163 . . . Oops.  That should be an `inner join` rather than a `left join`.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. That is really close. As I mentioned for the answer offered by Brian, I should have specified that a ClientID can have multiple DispositionIDs and the same SupervisorID can be assigned to each DispositionID. So, if a SupervisorID appears more than once for the same ClientID (e.g., the ClientID=6263 now has 2 DispositionIDs=1222 and =1220 both with the same SupervisorID=322) then I get multiple rows for that ClientID. I.e., it lists ClientID 6263 twice with the updated data. I need ClientID just once. I don't care what DispositionID is shown/lost. I've edit the original data.